# Alternativas ao MVC para aplicações Web

Tags: design-pattern, mvc

### Contexto (TL;DR)

Quando se fala em padrões de projeto arquiteturais, geralmente se fala em MVC. Para a web, geralmente utiliza-se algo como a imagem a seguir:

[image: Web MVC]

Tanto que grande parte dos frameworks que temos, como o Zend, Symfony, o Rails, entre outros, *geralmente* utilizam implementações deste padrão, e/ou suas variações/interpretações. Quando estudei a disciplina de Projetos de Sistemas, este também foi o padrão falado na maior parte do tempo. Os projetos eram feitos em MVC, as provas, em MVC, e o que falávamos nos pátios, era MVC.

### Meu caso

Certo dia, conversando com alguns colegas de trabalho, decidi por fazer um framework <sup>(loucura, não?!)</sup> para suportar as aplicações Web da empresa (em PHP), com suporte aos padrões da equipe, código legado, etc. Claro, com tanta influência, comecei a escrever o bendito em MVC mesmo, e já está em sua segunda versão *stable*.

No entanto, hoje me veio uma dúvida, se realmente fiz uma boa escolha ao optar por MVC, sendo que não considerei a existência de outros padrões, nem questionei o tal "absolutismo" dele.

### Perguntas

Em se tratando de padrões arquiteturais, quais alternativas temos **na literatura**, ao uso do MVC, e quais suas **vantagens e desvantagens** em relação a outros padrões, neste tipo de aplicação? Quais exemplos de renomados frameworks não-MVC podemos tomar?

---

**Observação importante**: *Meu objetivo com esta pergunta não é obter só uma lista de padrões, se fosse para isso, uma busca no Google bastava :) Estou bem mais interessado em saber suas vantagens e desvantagens para aplicações Web, para que possa tomar uma decisão **baseada em literatura**, estudos de caso, e não em opiniões pessoais de cada um.*

Comment: Xi! Só de arquiteturas MVC já existem várias variações variadas. O MVC "original", concebido para aplicações desktop em Smalltalk usava vários pequenos MVCs para uma tela -- parecido com o que alguns frameworks frontend vêm fazendo. A humanidade ainda não sabe responder essa pergunta a contento no contexto da Web, *you're in for trouble, little man!* =)

Comment: Um site com apenas páginas estáticas tira o M do MVC. Pode parecer algo jurássico, mas para sites simples que realizam uma única função, um banco de dados muitas vezes nem faz sentido. Como um site que calcula, traduz ou informa algo.

Comment: Será que realmente nada pode existir além do MVC e sua coleção de filhos ou adaptações?!

Comment: Quando se fala do assunto num contexto mais estrito de "aplicações Web", [templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template) (ex. XSLT, Smarty) e client-frameworks (ex. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript)) são bichos que pegam... Dando a cara final da sua arquitetura.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Já existe muitas variações do MVC, os próprios Symfony, CakePHP, CodeIgniter dizem utilizar o MVC, mas não é o padrão puro, dizem isso para não assustar a comunidade com as milhares de camadas que possuem.

Existem várias camadas que auxiliam as três camadas principais, como uma camada de serviço entre o controller e a model, camada de transferencias de objetos conhecida como DTO, repositório, entre o banco e a modelo e por ai vai.

A escolha de um framework para desenvolver um aplicativo é a principal decisão que um desenvolvedor pode tomar. Pois irá prender o sistema ao modelo adotado para o resto da vida, ou ser re-codificado.

Recomendo que leia no blog do criador do PHP, Rasmus Lerdorf, a [critica que ele faz sobre a moda de frameworks](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html). Ele critica a criação de tantas camadas, sendo que seria possível a mesma coisa de forma organizada e com muito mais performance.

Abaixo cito outras camadas que você poderá estudar caso tenha interesse.

**Serviço**

A camada de serviço fica entre os controller e as models. Nesta camada ficará toda a regra de negocio de uma ação, independente de uma interface com o usuário. Ao usar uma camada de serviço é possível isolar suas regras de negócio que envolvem mais do que manipulação de dados. Deixando o controller para lidar com o processamento que as views necessitam.

A principal vantagem seria a possibilidade de reescrever toda a sua camada de interação com usuário, ou mesmo criar várias, sem precisar se preocupar com as regras de negócio.

Um bom exemplo é a possibilidade de criar um aplicativo Web e um aplicativo para celular comunicando diretamente com a camada de serviço, onde cada um teria suas camadas de views e controllers.

Se utilizasse o MVC puro, muito código teria que ser reescrito nos controllers, pois as regras que a View impõem sobre o controller, pode requerer tratamentos ou mesmo retorno diferenciados.

**DTO**

O DTO é um padrão na verdade que te ajuda a padronizar os dados de comunicação entre as camadas, possibilitando em vários casos o uso de injeção de dependencia.

Utilizar DTO é uma excelente maneira de programar APIs ou lidar com webservices.

**Repositorio**

No conceito original do MVC, a model é responsável por toda a regra de negócio de utilização da informação do sistema, sendo assim, toda a manipulação e comunicação com o banco de dados ficam misturados ali dentro. A camada de repositório apareceu para separar a comunicação da manipulação, deixando mais legível e organizado todo o código da model, alem de possibilitar muito reaproveitamento de código.

**MVP**

Resumindo, é um modelo direto entre uma camada View e Presenter. Pense em um aplicativo onde a view faz requisições Javascript, e o próprio Javascript realiza toda a regra de negócio. É um modelo que vem crescendo muito devido a escalabilidade que possibilita.

[Veja a comparação entre as Frameworks neste modelo](https://moot.it/blog/technology/riotjs-the-1kb-mvp-framework.html),

[Saiba a diferença entre o MVC e o MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference).

--

Apesar das camadas acima citadas parecem ser somente padrões, elas atual como verdadeiras camadas, até mesmo nas frameworks que utilizamos. Um exemplo é o Doctrine que possui a camada de repositório e o Symfony criar suas camadas de modelo onde todo o código faz uso da camada de repositório para comunicar com o banco.

Vale a pena estudar um pouco sobre cada uma para visualizar bem como estão separadas as camadas.

Algumas outras sugestões [Hexagonal Architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) que não possuo muito conhecimento pra falar.

Comment: Atualmente, meu framework possui *apenas* três camadas, ele é bem leve e robusto para o que é demandado. Justamente como a imagem que postei na pergunta.

Comment: O seu comentário *Já existe muitas variações do MVC, os próprios Symfony, CakePHP, CodeIgniter dizem utilizar o MVC, mas não é o padrão puro*, praticamente respondeu parte da minha duvida (em outra [*pergunta*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60830/quando-o-controller-é-necessário)), acredito muito nisto que você disse. Obrigado mesmo :)

Answer (score 13):

### MVC como pattern?

Na verdade eu classifico o MVC mais como divisão de camadas do que um pattern puramente dito.

O MVC veio para distribuir a responsabilidade entre as camadas do projeto.

É muito fácil adicionar regra de negócio em meio a sua camada de VIEW, como isso você reduz a coesão e cria um alto acoplamento de suas classes. Quando temos o projeto separado em camadas podemos ter um melhor aproveitamento de código, maior coesão, menor acoplamento e assim vai.

Um framework baseado em MVC é bom pois ele facilita a utilização. Um desenvolvedor vai saber que basta mexer em determinado lugar para criar uma entrada no sistema e depois criar um local para receber e tratar a requisição.

### O que usar então?

Existem diversos patterns que podem ser utilizados para fazer com que seu framework fique realmente utilizável. Poderia citar alguns como:

- Front Controller
- Intercepting Filter
- View Helper
- Dispatcher to View
- Service to Worker

Note que esses padrõess podem ser utilizados em um projeto MVC. O correto seria entender o funcionamento desses padrões, mesmo sendo você desenvolvedor de outra linguagem, e aplicar ao seu projeto.

### Conclusão

O MVC é um padrão que funciona bem, ajuda a manter um código saudável e prático.

Lógico que até mesmo com o melhor framework do mundo na mão de um péssimo desenvolvedor não adiantará em nada.

O que importa é criar um framework bem feito e que possa ajudar de todo o modo possível.

Comment: Atualmente já possuo o Front Controller, o View Helper, e o Dispatcher. Estudarei a necessidade de incluir mais padrões na versão 3.

Comment: @CalebeOliveira Manutenção de framework tende a ficar bem difícil com o passar do tempo. Sugiro evitar adicionar features que sejam possíveis de resolver com uma biblioteca.

Answer (score 7):

Boas Calebe, 
  O MVC é uma optima escolha de pattern para uma web application, embora tenha sido criado para aplicações desktop, é uma escolha perfeita para a web pois separa as diversas camadas/tecnologia existentes numa aplicação web, M -> ORM/SQL, V -> HTML/CSS/JS, C -> C#/PHP, etc...

O MVC ofereçe também a classica separação em três camadas, dados, lógica, apresentação.

Mais o que mais gosto é o principio que ele oferece e que procuro usar em todos os meus projectos, MVC ou não, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Existem já algumas derivações do MVC, tais como o HMVC, MVVM, MVP, etc ... em que cada uma se adapta bem ao problema a resolver.

Eu particularmente gosto de usar o HMVC, pois é o MVC separado em vários módulos/triads, e até estou a fazer uma framework HMVC :) "(loucura, não !?)", que por sinal é super fléxivel e rápida :)

http://pedrosimoes79.github.io/silverbullet/

PS: Atenção é apenas uma preferência minha.

O HMVC permite por exemplo, ter uma triade MVC para tratar de vários blocos de layout, como o header e o footer, nas views ou controlador da aplicação, posso simplesmente chamar o controlador 'layout/header' e depois no final o 'layout/footer', sem nunca precisar de sujar o controlador chamado, quem diz layout, diz outras coisas.

Este é um diagrama HMVC, embora na minha framework também se possa chamar uma triade MVC de uma view, como se fosse template:

[image: HMVC Pattern]

e uns videos a explicar o HMVC usando CodeIgniter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ