# Como implementar um sistema de login num padrão MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, post, get

Estou estudando sobre [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) com [php](/questions/tagged/php), consegui fazer um sistema simples de início, só que fiquei com dúvidas em alguns pontos, como posso implementar meu sistema de login? por onde devo "pegar" os valores de `POST` e/ou `GET` por onde devo tratar os valores pra evitar *sql injection* e *XSS*, `Model` ou `Controller`?

Comment: Você está utilizando algum framework ou está fazendo do zero na mão?

Comment: Estou fazendo à mão mesmo,pra estudar.

Comment: Então você é quem deve definir as regras do seu sistema, pode tanto ser no controller quanto no model, depende apenas de qual paradigma vc pretende usar

Answer (score 4):

O padrão MVC possui três camadas

- **View**: Suas views são as formas de apresentação de dados para o usuário. Em suma seria um html, flash, air, ou qualquer que seja o tipo de interface que irá adotar. Na view não deve possuir nenhuma regra de negócio, a não ser blocos de comandos simples como um `for` ou `foreach` para apresentar uma lista de registros.
- **Controller**: O controller irá tratar da comunicação entre a view e a model. Aqui você irá tratar dados recebidos da requisição, enviar para métodos da model, e passar e apresentar a devida view. Aqui tambem pode ter regas como envio de email, validação de permissão, etc.
- **Model**: A model deve ficar toda sua regra de negócio relacionada ao banco de dados. Qualquer que seja a consulta ou manipulação de dados deve ficar aqui dentro.

Para ser mais específico com sua pergunta, o formulário ficaria na view, no controller receberá os dados, e gravar sessões e cookies, e para consultar os dados no banco você utilizará as suas models.

**Dicas**

Existe algumas camadas que podem ser adicionadas que aumentam a possibilidade de reaproveitamento de código como uma camada chamada service, que seria uma camada onde ficaria regras não relacionadas com os dados, porem de muita importância.

Na camada service poderia conter uma classe chamada `Autenticação` por exemplo com métodos que possam verificar se um usuário está logado, pois utiliza a sessão ou cookie e não o banco de dados, ou mesmo para o registro de usuários que alem de cadastrar no banco de dados utilizando a model, deve enviar um email de confirmação.

Utilizar uma camada service possibilita que várias regras sejam reutilizadas em todos os controllers.

Você pode encontrar maiores informações sobre o [MVC aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4474/alternativas-ao-mvc-para-aplicacoes-web/4482#4482) assim como, dicas para criar [sistemas autenticação seguros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php?rq=1).