# Quando o controller é necessário?

Tags: mvc

Raramente usei MVC pelo simples fato de *me* parecer que cada pessoa usa a sua maneira, eu sei que o MVC veio antes da web, ao ler estes links tive uma sensação que parece que o entendimento de uma pessoa não é o mesmo de outra para o uso do MVC:

- [O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/3635)
- [PHP, MVC e hello world!](http://elias.praciano.com/php-mvc-e-hello-world/)

O segundo link menciona que os Controllers não são obrigatórios e eles só devem ser usados em `actions` (ações do usuário). Se entendi o que ele disse o View é o responsável direto por entregar os dados ao cliente (visualmente falando) e ele se comunica com o Model diretamente também (sem interferência do Controller), já o Controller se comunica com o Model somente quando há ação do usuário e não é responsável por entregar nada (parece que este ponto é concordância da maioria).

### Frameworks populares que usam MVC (tentam usar?!?)

Três frameworks muitos populares são o CodeIgniter, Laravel e o cakePHP. Todos trabalham as Rotas usando o Controller, exemplo com Laravel:

routes.php:

```
<?php
Route::resource('', 'DemoController');
```

DemoController.php:

```
<?php
    class DemoController extends BaseController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            //Chama o views/Demo/index.blade.php
            return View::make('Demo.index', compact('data'));
        }

    ...
```

DemoModel:

index.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id='content'>
Output: {{ $data }}!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

O equivalente em cakePHP:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::connect('/', ['controller' => 'DemoController', 'action' => 'index']);
```

e cria o arquivo `ctp`

O equivalente no codeigneter:

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'DemoController';
```

controller:

```
class DemoController extends Controller {
    private $data;

    public function __construct(){
         parent::Controller();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['helloworld'] = 'Hello World';
        $this->load->view('Demo', $this->data);
    }
}
```

### A duvida

**Se** *eu* entendi, apesar dos dados do Model não passarem pelo Controller ainda sim o Controller fica responsável por chamar o Model e o View (ao menos nos frameworks citados), ou o Controller chama o View e este chama o Model, de qualquer maneira o controller é o gatilho (se entendi corretamente).

Em outras palavras, querendo ou não em Web o Controller sempre vai *se* fazer necessário, não só por questões de rotas, mas também pelo simples motivo de qualquer coisa em uma página de web apresentar o sentido CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete), ao abrir o página inicial de um site estamos fazendo um READ, não?

Então a minha duvida é: Os frameworks ao usarem Controllers estão errados ou qualquer requisição HTTP é considerada uma `action` e isto tecnicamente seria ação do usuário (o que obrigaria as rotas a serem Controllers)?

<sub>Ou realmente ninguém usa MVC estritamente?</sub>

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é MVP e MVVM?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21539)

Comment: Opinião pessoal, acho que controller em backend é algo que tende a deixar de existir, uma vez que tendo modelo que define regras de acesso e representação, vc precisa apenas de uma interface para entregar em algum protocolo como REST, WebSocket, ou formato não padrão (que é o único que se beneficia de uma controladora, normalmente substituível por um callback no router). MVC é uma separação de responsabilidades interessante, mas que fazia sentido quando não usava-mos SPA, hoje em dia adota-la tende a adicionar complexidade desnecessária no backend. Já no frontend é outra história :)

Comment: @GabrielGartz Parece bem lógico o seu comentário, eu procurei SPA, mas não achei, seria SOA (Service Oriented Architecture)?

Comment: SPA é Single Page Application (onde o seu site, se comporta como um aplicativo, carregando data e módulos da forma mais eficiente possível e apenas trafegando data para povoar a interface e operações que podem ser feitas no cliente em vez do servidor), normalmente está fortemente relacionada a um SOA ou SaaS. Mas estes são outra camada de arquitetura da sua aplicação, que podem ser desenvolvidos combinando com MVC ou outros padrões de arquitetura para obter os resultados desejados.

Comment: @GabrielGartz Eu analizei um framework não tão popular e sua documentação, o [*mini2*](http://www.dev-metal.com/mini2-extremely-simple-barebone-php-application-top-slim/), na versão 1 ele usava os controllers, mas na versão 2 ele usa apenas Views e Models combinado as funções anonimas para as rotas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bem legal essa framework, não conhecia, apenas conhecia o SLIM pra PHP, acho legal essa onda que PHP developers estão copiando o estilo funcional do Node (e suas libs), acho mais simples e menos verboso que as frameworks que tentam copiar o Java, sendo que até hoje o PHP não tem propriedade tipada e usar métodos mágicos pra tal é uma solução terrível. Mas não vamos fugir muito do assunto, se quiser bater um papo sobre esses assuntos fora dos comentários me adiciona no FB. :)

Answer (score 9):

Todos os frameworks web que conheço possuem Controladores, de uma forma ou de outra.

## O papel do Controlador

Pense no **Controlador** como o responsável pela lógica de navegação entre as páginas.

Por exemplo, é ele quem vai decidir qual tela será exibida após a submissão de um formulário, que pode ser o próprio formulário com uma mensagem de erro de validação ou uma outra tela com a mensagem de sucesso.

## Diferentes tipos de Controladores

Um controlador também é aquele que contém os métodos executados após alguma requisição do usuário.

Entretanto, muitos frameworks, incluindo aqueles que usam esquema de rotas, usam o padrão conhecido como ***Front Controller***, que seria um tipo de Super Controlador que recebe todas as requisições, faz algum tratamento inicial e então delega a resposta efetiva a um controlador específico da aplicação que implementa o framework.

## Acessando o Model

Quanto ao modo de acesso ao `Model`, se passa ou não pelo Controlador, a forma recomendada é exatamente como os exemplos da pergunta.

Note que a View não está *acessando* o modelo diretamente, no sentido de invocar uma consulta ao banco de dados, mas está recebendo os objetos já pesquisados pelo controlador.

O Controlador, sabendo qual é a requisição do usuário, consulta o model, recupera um ou mais objetos e passa como parâmetro ou através de um mapa de propriedades para a View. Ou seja, não é que a View não possa acessar o modelo, mas é o Controlador quem possui os dados necessários para selecionar qual é o Model adequado.

Por outro lado, seria errado implementar, por exemplo, uma consulta ao banco de dados ou chamada direta aos métodos de consulta do model a partir da View, porque isso quebraria vários princípios de uma boa arquitetura, tais como divisão de responsabilidades (coesão), atravessamento de camadas e outros).

## MVCs diferentes?

Na verdade, não vejo muitas implementações diferentes do MVC para web.

Existem variações comuns, por exemplo na forma como o controlador passa informações para o Model. Algumas implementações usam *hashes*, outras parâmetros, outras atributos no controlador e assim por diante. Outras variações incluem a forma como se mapeia as URLs e os métodos dos controladores (convenção de nomes, anotações, rotas) e a forma como o Controlador define a View a ser exibida.

Em contrapartida, existem também as implementações *erradas*. Como principal exemplo cito as páginas em PHP que, num mesmo script, contém validação de parâmetros, acesso ao banco e escrita de HTML.

## Actions e Requisições

Na maioria das vezes, uma Ação (*Action*) é equivalente a uma Requisição no sentido de que, após uma ação do usuário como clique num link ou botão, o navegador vai gerar uma requisição HTTP, a qual será redirecionada para o método do controlador conforme a configuração.

Dê uma olhada neste outra resposta falando sobre [frameworks MVC *action based*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22707/227).

Entretanto, muitas vezes o termo *action* é associado com frameworks

Comment: Isto incluí ações que não são do usuário necessariamente ou qualquer requisição HTTP é uma "ação de usuário"? Se entendi o que disse (*O Controlador, sabendo qual é a requisição do usuário, consulta o model, recupera um ou mais objetos e passa como parâmetro ou através de um mapa de propriedades para a View*), então me parece que o segundo link (mencionado em minha pergunta) está bastante errado. Desculpe se não entendi algo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Atualizei a resposta com um último tópico. Pelo que vi no artigo, minha resposta está em pleno acordo, não está errado. Talvez o que esteja confundindo seja o uso de vários termos para significar a mesma coisa, ou de um termo para falar de coisas diferentes.  Infelizmente, só lendo bastante sobre o assunto para ficar mais fácil de compreender tudo isso.

Comment: lendo sua resposta agora melhor, parece que é isto mesmo, só uma ainda tenho duvida (me informe se necessitar formular uma pergunta para isto), o Model fica responsavel por selecionar o View adequado (é o que me parece mais lógico) ou o Controller lê os dados e repassa ao View antes de entrega-lo? Digo isto, pois no desenho [**Action Based**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd2S5.png) me parece que o Controller devolve o View, mas não sei se este View veio em reposta do Model ou se o Controller verificou os dados vindos do Model e selecionou um View adequado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A view é sempre acionada a partir do controller. Em MVC, o Model pode ser acessado pela View para exibir os dados, mas o modelo **nunca** determina qual View será exibida, afinal é justamente o propósito do MVC separar os dados da apresentação.

Comment: Entendi @utluiz, entendi, eu acho que a questão que me causou confusão no entendimento não é como os frameworks são "propostos" e nem por causa do Action, mas sim por causa que estes frameworks permitem uma certa "liberdade", ou seja o framework não vai te limitar se você não seguir o "padrão". Poderia adicionar o seu comentário a resposta, ao meu ver é bem pertinente ao entendimento da responsabilidade do "controller", ao que entendi o dados do Model podem passar dentro do controller, mas não estão vinculados :) Grato.

Answer (score 3):

O MVC está relacionado na organização da sua aplicação, o Controller é a camada intermediária entre o Model e View.
No exemplo que você citou não está demonstrando todo o potencial do Controller, no controller você acionar Handlers("gatilhos") e executar varios processos, relacionado a outras Models.
Num processo de compra de um site de e-commerce, quando um usuário finaliza uma compra é gerado um processo:
->gerar conta no cartão do cliente, processo com API do cartão do crédito
->baixa no estoque;
->envio de e-mail de confirmação de compra;
->informar a transportadora sobre o pedido( via email ou  via sistema);
...

Dai se faz necessário o Controller, ele é quem vai iniciar esse processos, ou os iniciar gatilhos para esses processos.

Comment: Tá você descreveu o `action` que dispara uma ação CRUD (ao menos é isso que entendi), mas não explicou em uma ação onde supostamente não tem ação do usuário, aonde o cenário seria apenas a resposta ao cliente e as rotas (como a página index). Note que em todos frameworks PHP citados, as rotas são Controllers e basicamente eles chamam os Views (e as vezes chamam os models também), como seria neste sentido?

Comment: O Controller não se faz necessário quando sua aplicação é um site institucional, para isso o Laravel permite nas rotas, que você retorne a view sem fazer uso do controller.
EX: Route::get('/', function(){
 return view("site.home");

});

Comment: EX: Route::get('/', function(){
 return view("site.home");

});

Comment: Entendo, então é possivel fazer uma rota no Laravel usando apenas Routes, Model e View? Então isto faz o uso de `Route::resource` ser errado fora de ações do usuário, certo? O CodeIgnter e o cakePHP possuem funções semelhantes?

Comment: Não sei, eu só o Laravel, que aliás um excelente framework.

Comment: Eu também concordo, Laravel é bem elegante se comparado aos outros, na verdade o Laravel nem é um framework, ele é um conjunto de frameworks :)

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de enxergar as camadas do MVC é seguinte:

Imagine seu sistema como uma caixinha.

## Visualização como fronteira

A camada de visualização é a parte do seu sistema que se comunica com o mundo exterior. São as bordas da caixa, as paredes. Todo o núcleo do seu sistema está escondido dentro da caixa e qualquer interação com o mundo exterior (pode ser uma interação com o usuário através de uma interface gráfica, navegador, outros sistemas, outras partes externas do seu sistema) é gerenciada pelas suas fronteiras. No MVC esse camada é chamada de *View*, ou *Visualização*, pois normalmente ela é responsável pela apresentação de dados para o usuário por meio de uma interface e por receber entradas do usuário (submissão de formulários, cliques, qualquer tipo de interação) e traduzir para um formato que seu sistema entenda. Mas ela pode ser muito mais do que isso e ser utilizada como uma camada que sabe conversar com o mundo exterior ao seu sistema; a vantagem dessa aproximação é que você pode desenhar o funcionamento interno do seu sistema da maneira que for melhor, deixando a camada de visualização (fronteira) com a responsabilidade de transformar os dados que saem do seu sistema para outros formatos (numa aplicação web ela poderia transformar seus dados em uma página HTML, ou em um JSON que vai ser enviado à outro sistema pra que haja integração, etc) e que traduza dados externos (dados provenientes de formulários, outros sistemas) para um formato que seu sistema entenda. Ou seja, se o formato em que você se comunica com outras unidades muda você só precisa que essa camada seja modificada, sem que haja necessidade de mexer "dentro da caixa".

## Controladoras como contextos

Os dados (ou interações) recebidos pela camada de visualização (fronteira) são repassados para sua camada de controle que decide o que fazer com eles. Se você recebeu a submissão de um formulário de uma página web que requer atualização de algum dado no seu sistema a camada de controle vai disparar essa operação; se precisar mandar um e-mail de notificação para o usuário após uma determinada requição, esta camada será responsável por isso.

Ela também é responsável por mandar de volta pra camada de fronteira o resultado dessas requisições, em algum formato definido como padrão no seu sistema, para que esse por sua vez possa dar uma resposta para o agente externo que solicitou a requisição (um exemplo seria a camada de controle mandar para a camada de visualização uma lista de dados para que ela renderize uma página HTML no navegador). Mas note que a camada de controle não deveria se preocupar com o formato em que esses dados serão apresentados no mundo exterior, isso é uma responsabilidade da fronteira. Seu sistema não conhece nada que esteja fora da caixa.

Pode-se pensar na camada de controle como a camada que orquestra o funcionamento do sistema: ela controla o fluxo de execução das coisas e repassa dados de um lado para o outro.

Note que apesar de muitas vezes alguns frameworks orientados a objectos desenharem sua camada de controle inteira como um único objeto/método, um fluxo de execução da camada de pode (e em muitos casos deve) ser quebrado em vários objetos pequenos, cada um com sua responsabilidade bem definida.

## Modelos como entidades do domínio

Os models do seu sistema são a representação do seu domínio da aplicação dentro do seu sistema. Eles representam os dados que são manipulados pelas interações disparadas pela camada de controle.

Diferente do que é imposto ou sugerido por muitos frameworks, sua camada de modelo não precisa (nem deve) estar intrinsicamente ligada a um banco de dados. Uma prática saudável no desenvolvimento de aplicações é definir sua camada de modelo de acordo com as necessidades da aplicação e manter uma camada adicional de mapeamento entre o modelo de dados e a solução de armazenamento em si (que pode ser um único banco de dados relacional, um banco nosql, um cache, uma api externa ou uma mistura de todos). Isso permite mais flexibilidade no seu sistema e faz com que mudanças nas estratégias de armazenamento sejam facilitadas, desacoplando essas duas funções (manipulação de dados e armazenamento).

Um ótimo recurso que explica melhor esse tipo de aproximação no desenvolvimento de aplicações é esta [palestra do Uncle Bob na conferência Ruby Midwest de 2011](https://youtu.be/WpkDN78P884). Apesar de ele usar alguns conceitos de Ruby como exemplo acho que o conteúdo é acessível mesmo para quem não conhece a linguagem e muito útil independente da tecnologia que você usa para desenvolver aplicações.

Comment: Estou começando a achar o MVC menos funcional que o HMVC em aplicações web, tal como chamar mais de uma controlador em uma requisição e sub-controladores, etc. O que acha?