# Como implementar um Sistema de Rotas no MVC?

Tags: mvc, route, rotas, routing

Estou criando um Framework MVC (mais para estudos), e estou tentando implementar um **sistema de rotas**, mas não sei bem como/onde executar as rotas. Então gostaria de saber se há algum fluxo de execução de um projeto MVC.

O meu está mais ou menos assim:

```
// Função que inicia a aplicação
RUN() {

   // Aqui faço as chamadas padrões, detecto qual é o Controller e Action
   // da requisição
   Request $request = new Request();

   // Pego o Controller;
   string $controller = $request->getController();

   // Pego a Action
   string $action = $request->getAction();

   // Instâncio o Controller
   Controller $app = New $controller($request);

   string $output = $app->{$action}();

   // Imprimo o resultado (view)
   output($output);

}
```

[Código Fonte](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base/blob/6c0c6003db4efd57df286994aff0f3fabdf604fd/base/core/application.class.php)

A execução do controller e action continuaria no escopo acima, ou dentro do escopo da rota?

Ví que alguns sistemas de rotas (quase todos na verdade), utilizam um "*Handler*" (_callback) para a rota. Nesse caso onde ficaría a *action*?

Obs: Estou fazendo o *framework* em PHP, mas busco uma resposta mais "teórica", como um algorítimo independente de linguagem, pode ser no mesmo estilo do código que coloquei acima, sem  muitos detalhes, só a lógica mesmo.

<sub>Obs²: A resposta não precisa ser um TCC. :P</sub>

Comment: Essa pergunta pode te ajudar > http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60830/quando-o-controller-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio

Comment: Obrigado LucaoA, com certeza vai ajudar muito. :D

Comment: As rotas geralmente são executadas por um "Dispatcher", que é o cara responsável por Dispachar a requisição. Dê uma olhada no framework que eu fiz de zoeira [PHPLegends/Maxters](https://github.com/phplegends/Maxters). Ele usa uns componentes que são instalados via composer, dentre eles o [PHPLegends/Routes](https://github.com/phplegends/routes)

Comment: Não é jabá! dá uma olhada no [exemplo](https://github.com/phplegends/routes/blob/master/examples/index.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Costumo fazer da seguinte forma:

Collection - A coleção que vai guardar todas as rotas.

Route - A classe que representa uma rota. Você deve fornecer informações como a uri que deseja capturar e verbos http aceitos.

Router - A classe que serve para fazer a ponte entre Route e Collection. É um facilitador para criar rotas dentro da coleção.

DispatcherInterface - A interface que fornece um método a ser executado como o despachante da rota. Preferi fazer uma interface para poder atender a diversas implementações, por exemplo, alguém que quer usar uma biblioteca mais complexa ou que queria simplesmente usar menos recursos.

Então, nesse contexto, teríamos uma estrutura mais ou menos assim:

```
$router = new Router(new Collection);

// Cria a instância de Route, coloca dentro da Collection
// E retorna Rota recém-criada, para possíveis outra definições 

$router->get('/', 'HomeController::getIndex'); 

$router->get('/login', function () {})->setName('home.login');

// Classe que implementa DispatcherInterface
$router->dispatch(new Dispatcher());
```

Baseando no contexto apresentado na pergunta, creio que uma interessante seria:

```
$request = new Request();

// retorna new Response se tudo der certo

$response = $router->dispatch(new RequestDispatcher($request)); 


$response->send();
```

Dentro do seu `RequestDispatcher`, você poderia aplicar as devidas operações para chamar Controller e Método.

Por exemplo:

```
   class RequestDispatcher implements DispatcherInterface {

       public function __construct(Request $request) {
               $this->request = $request;
       }

       public function dispatch(Router $router) {
            $route = $router->findByRequest($this->request);

            if (! $route) return $this->notFound();

            $response = call_user_func($route->callAction(), $route->getParameters());

            return $response;


       }
   }
```

Ou seja, no seu Dispatcher, você pode adicionar as operações necessárias para procurar a rota dentro da coleção. Quando não for encontrada, você pode invocar uma ação para o laçamento do erro 404. Quando é encontrado, você pode chamar a ação definida para a determinada url e chamá-la, retornando então um Response.

Tentando resumir isso tudo:

O Dispatcher procura pela rota dentro de uma coleção de rotas, que foi criada pelo router. Em seguida, se o Dispatcher encontra a rota, ele converte o retorno da ação da rota (Pode ser um método de um Controller ou uma Closure) para uma Response, que finalmente é enviada para o saída.

Você citou na sua pergunta a respeito de um Handler, que é passado através de um callback.

Creio que você está falando de uma função anônima, que algumas bibliotecas costumam utilizar para "amarrar" uma determinada funcionalidade para uma rota a fim de ser executada no final.

Na minha biblioteca também fiz isso. Posso usar tanto um método de uma classe (o Controller) como uma função anônima. Creio que isso seja muito útil em casos onde a rota não faça sentido apontar para um controller específico, por não ser algo que não tenha "relacionamento" com o restante.

Exemplo:

```
   $router->get('/json/cep/{num}', function ($number) {

        $url = sprintf('https://cep.correios.com.br/%s.json', $number);

        $dados = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

        // Transforma em JsonResponse
        return $dados;
   });
```

Comment: Legal Wallace, consegui compreender bastante a ideia. Só faltou falar do _handler_, que inclusive tu colocou um "exemplo: `$router->get('/login', function () {})->setName('home.login');`, que seria aquela função anônima. Me explica também esse _name_ `home.login`, já vi em outros lugares, seria o `controller.action`? Valeu!

Comment: @KaduAmaral seria um nome interno para a rota. Ao invés de você fazer `redirect('/login')` você faria `redirect_route('home.login')`. É apenas uma maneira de organizar melhor, nomeando as rotas