# Controller precisa ser uma class?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Os *controllers* dentro de um MVC, precisam ser classes? Pois pelo que estou vendo aqui, a única função deles é pegar as informações que o *view* ta pedindo, jogar pro *model* "resolver o problema" e quando estiver com problema resolvido, ele pega a solução pronta e manda pro *view* de novo... É mesmo necessário ele ser uma classe?

Comment: Isso vai depender de quem fez a tal Framework, nada impede que seja feita de outra forma, mas, o padrão estabelecido por todos que eu já mexi é um classe. Se você programar e fazer um próprio pode estabelecer a sua maneira, ou seja, depende mesmo de quem o faça, não é regra é assim que todos programa atualmente.

Comment: Mas, sinceridade eu pergunto porque tal questionamento, você acha que é um erro porque?

Comment: MVC não tem relação com orientação a objetos. O problema é que MVC em HTTP é que ficou "estranho", eu mesmo fiz essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60830/3635, pois Controllers parecem mais "coerentes" em aplicações que são disparados por sinais (independente de ser OOP), como um aplicativo desktop, cujo um botão irá fazer uma lista ser populada através de um Model (dados abstraidos e afins).

Comment: Lucas, só pra constar, conheço um Framework php que usa funções normais para fazer os Controllers, é antigo e meio "mal feito", mas é um exemplo de como OOP não tem ligação alguma com isto. Agora falando do que pode ser interessante do uso do OOP com Controller, seria organizar, simplesmente organizar, baseado em verbos (post, get, put), ou paths, ou qualquer coisa assim.

Comment: Virgilio, não acho que seja um erro, so questionei, porque por exemplo, uma classe, é tecnicamente um arquivo maior do que um arquivo PHP comum, dependendo, então seria mais fácil, pra determinadas situações, criar sem classe. Por exemplo, eu preciso de um controlller so pra pegar os dados do usuário no banco de dados, então precisarei criar todo o processo do MVC, pra poder ter isso. Mas acho que vale a pena, caso o sistema esteja maior

Comment: @LucasCarvalho experiência pessoal (ok, são só pouco mais de 15 anos mexendo com PHP, talvez não seja muito) - PHP sem MVC e sem OOP é muito mais simples e fácil de manter. Afinal, não é linguagem de programação, e sim uma mera coleção de _scripts_ de vida curta ao longo da execução da aplicação. Não vejo sentido em querer imitar estruturas complexas que fazem sentido em coisas monolíticas (quando fazem), como executáveis. Tratar o PHP como PHP facilita a vida. Um bom exemplo disso são as "rotas" tradicionais: quase nunca são necessárias numa aplicação bem pensada.

Comment: Bacco, eu por ser amante de PHP, fico ofendido em "ouvir" isso de um programador de 15 anos de carreira. PHP é uma linguagem de programação SIM e se bem usada, pode fazer coisas fantásticas, como podemos ver por exemplo o Magento, o WordPress, e muitas outras. Eu estou agora nesse exato momento criando uma plataforma EAD, e aplicando MVC, conforme as respostas que tive aqui, ja deu pra ter uma ideia, e tenho certeza que vai ser muito bem funcional, vai ser de fácil manutenção por conta de OOP e MVC, e ainda vai ser rápida! PHP ja deixou faz tempo, de ser apenas uma linguagem de scripts!

Comment: Uma coleção de scripts bem feitos é fantástico sim. E eu uso PHP no meu dia a dia. Não preciso "enfeitar" o PHP e folhear a ouro pra isso. Eu não ficaria ofendido se você me dissesse que minha chave de fenda é só uma chave de fenda. Afinal, é pra isso que ela foi criada. Não vou usar meu soprador de SMD pra tirar um parafuso. Não vejo razão pra ofensa em por cada coisa em seu lugar. Mas quando o pessoal não entende o que eu falo sobre linguagens de script, eu costumo perguntar "qual é o loop principal do seu programa em PHP?", para clarear um pouco a diferença. Ser script não é detrimento :)

Comment: Isto posto, de qualquer forma, a intenção não foi ofender. Sinto que tenha sido visto desta forma. Espero que consiga reler e ver que não há nada de mal no que foi dito.

Comment: Tudo bem, sem desavenças! Mas, pra mim, como eu disse, PHP depois da versão 5, não é somente uma linguagem de scripts!

Comment: O Fato de eu dizer ofendido, foi por conta de que estou me formando um profissional PHP, e acho que todas as linguagens devem ser valorizadas! E acho sim, que da pra criar coisas fantásticas com PHP junto a OOP, MVC, etc... Eu por exemplo, não saberia me organizar no  no PHP sem OOP, iria ficar uma bagunça, e de difícil manutenção.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho não relacionado ao assunto específico, mas vale lembrar que você já tem pontos para participar do chat da rede se quiser. Em especial, a sala "estouro de pilha" https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/ que é onde o pessoal do SOpt costuma ficar (durante o exoediente costuma ter movimento lá).

Comment: Obrigado Bacco :D

Comment: @LucasCarvalho a palavra amante aí é chave. Amante é quem tem amor. Amor tem quem é amador. Profissional se aprofunda, entende **todos** os conceitos necessários, faz relações, aprende com os mais experientes e fundamenta todas suas decisões. Claro que você pode ter a opinião que quiser, não tem nada de errado nisso. Mas opiniões sem fundamentos é algo só seu. É um direito seu, mas não muda o fato.Se você ama uma pessoa é ela é uma pessoa ruim, ninguém tem direito de dizer que não pode amá-la, mas as pessoas podem dizer que ela é ruim, o fato é que ela é ruim. Claro, seria bom a crítica ter...

Comment: ...fundamento. E o que o @Bacco está dizendo tem fundamento. Existe vasta gama de informação, até mesmo aqui no site que comprovam tudo o que ele disse. PHP pode fazer coisas fantásticas, ainda que eu discorde dos seus exemplos como fantásticas (todos os profissionais experientes - qualitativamente e não quantitativamente - que eu conheço não as consideram fantásticas, são coisas úteis, mas o produto no geral muito mal construído). Suas opiniões foram publicadas, legal. Mas fora o que eu já disse elas não se sustentam. Sua formação estará completa quando entender tudo o que eu estou falando...

Comment: Quando tiver todos os fundamentos para sustentar o que diz ou admitir que é só uma opinião, um gosto. E gosto não se discute.Ninguém está dizendo o que você deve ou não fazer, menos ainda do que deve ou não gostar. Estamos lhe ajudando entender melhor algo que pode ser útil para você. Se achar que não é fique a vontade para ignorar, a maioria das pessoas fazem isto. A maioria das pessoas que programam na área não são profissionais, elas nunca se formam por completo, mas sempre é um direito de cada um. O mercado tem bastante espaço para as pessoas que preferiram não ser profissionais, até ...

Comment: porque todo mundo começa sem ser profissional. Só uma última coisa: nunca conheci um programador iniciante que soubesse fazer OOP certo. Bem poucas pessoas experientes fazem OOP certo. OOP é muito difícil. O que o Bacco falou é muito mais fácil. OOP tem suas vantagens, mas só se fizer certo, no local certo. Eu falo disso no site o tempo todo, mas poucos leem. Claro que se pegar uma receita de bolo OOP e fizer igual pode ficar bom, mas a mínima alteração que faça naquilo já pode desmoronar tudo, e é o que acontece. E isto não é programar. Funcionar não é a mesma coisa que estar certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, tecnicamente não tem que ser, mas a maneira como todo mundo implementa é através de uma classe.

Se fizer de outra forma pode até ser melhor, pode estar inovando de certa forma, indo contra a maré de uma forma positiva. Mas pode fazer tudo errado por não ter experiência com aquilo e por não ter nada nada que já foi testando e validado por outras pessoas para "copiar". Pode ser um tiro no escuro... e pode compensar :)

Mas se usar classe para todo o resto e no *controller* não, aí acho estranho.

Sua compreensão do padrão está correto, implementá-lo corretamente é mais importante.

Se for inovar no *controller* talvez não precise do MVC. De fato há uma corrente já questionando o seu uso, e não falo de um ou outro *outsider* como eu, de fato já existem formas mais adequadas para muitos cenários.

Comment: Alguém pode justificar o -1 na resposta dele por favor?