# Dúvida em relação ao MVC

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Estou fazendo meu primeiro projeto usando o MVC no PHP, e me deparei com essa dúvida:

Em relação ao `ajax` e `requisições assíncronas`, quando eu for fazer uma requisição a uma página, essa página que processa a requisição do ajax seria o controller

(Ex: **view-ajax** ~> **controller-php** ~> **model-php**)

Ou eu teria que fazer uma página que é chamada pelo ajax e essa página chama o controller?

(Ex: **view-ajax** ~> **pagina-auxiliar** ~> **controller-php** ~> **model-php**)

Obrigado!

Comment: Caro Leandro não vejo desta forma, vejo o ajax como uma ação e só, aliais nem precisa de ter uma controller.php para um model.php especifico e página auxiliares, aliais muito uso de MVC nem checa ser MVC, até mesmo a ideia de implementar MVC de muita gente podem simplesmente estar erradas, mas as pessoas fazem assim mesmo, MVC não é tecnologia e não necessariamente tem uma receita de bolo correta ou exata, nem tudo precisa de MVC, ambos exemplos podem estar corretos ou errados, não dá pra ter uma certeza da forma que descreveu, mas para resumir acho que deveria olhar outros FWs...

Comment: ...antes de implementar a sua propria ideia, tem muita gente que faz isso, falam que OOP é melhor, que procedural é ruim, que MVC depende de OOP, mas é um monte de falacias, inclusive tem uma pergunta minha sobre o HTTP e o MVC: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60830/3635 ... pode ter certeza que aqui na sua pergunta vão sair varias respostas que parecem corretas, mas que podem ser uma série de equívocos.

Comment: Tem algumas perguntas semelhante, mas achei interessante responder a sua para exemplificar o qual o papel do controller no padrão mvc. Mas por curiosidade, está utilizando algum framework php?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhuma framework, pois não tenho prática em nenhum. Eu normalmente programo em Java, usando o Hibernate. E no caso, o propósito é passar o meu projeto de TCC feito em procedural para OOP, apenas para estudo do PHP na parte de padrões de projeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, vou tentar descrever de forma simples e objetiva. Seu primeiro exemplo está mais correto na minha opinião.

No padrão básico de MVC o **controller** tem a função de ser o "*cara*" responsável por agir diante de uma requisição (rota) e possivelmente se relacionar com **models** ou com **views** para entregar o que foi solicitado. Ele é o controlador das ações. Por tanto, não vejo razão para não utilizar diretamente o controller.

Na minha visão está correto sua **view** fazer a requisição ajax para uma **rota** e que esta chame o **controller** para consultar informações de um **model** e responder com estes dados. Ao menos é assim que funciona na maioria dos frameworks que conheço.